# Setting up an XLR microphone for PS4 and PC (with Astro A40 MixAmp)

Tags: behringer, streaming

I'm currently using an Astro A40 Mixamp's stream port to supply all audio from my PS4 (game, party, mic) to the line-in on my PC.

I'm now looking to incorporate an XLR microphone that I can use on both my PS4, and my PC. I've been looking at the [Behringer 502](https://www.gear4music.com/PA-DJ-and-Lighting/Behringer-XENYX-Q502USB-USB-Mixer/IPI), however I'm unsure how the setup would work.

My current thought process is...

1. Astro Mixamp receives party/game audio from PS4 via optical.
2. Mixer line 1 receives XLR mic.
3. Mixer line 2/3 receives Astro Mixamp stream port (only party/audio).
4. Mixer USB outputs to PS4 (only mic).
5. Mixer main outputs to line-in on PC (all audio)

Is this achievable? My assumption is the USB output would also include line 2/3 which would cause a feedback loop?

Comment: Did you ever get this set up working? I am currently looking for an answer to this question as well.

Comment: @Sepehr I purchased a GoXLR to replace the Astro MixAmp; would highly recommend!

Comment: Thanks for the update! Do you get all the software EQ features that Astro MixAmp provides? Specifically frequency tuning and having EQ presets.

Comment: Sadly it doesn't have as many EQ features for output, but the developers are actively making improvements, and very open to suggestions and conversations for improvements. Check out their Discord for more https://discord.me/helicongaming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my hardware needs by purchasing a [GoXLR](https://www.tc-helicon.com/broadcast) from TC Helicon.

The GoXLR enables audio routing to/from various sources effortlessly via software, and I would highly recommended it. One of the GoXLR inputs (as the name might suggest) is XLR, but the mixer also supports aux line-in so can be used with the Astro A40 headset.

Setup

- GoXLR mixer (replaces Astro mixer)
- 3.5mm TRRS splitter ([Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/B079PRB7BK/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_search_asin_image?ie=UTF8&psc=1))
- Optional headset cable to remove the mute button ([Amazon](https://www.amazon.co.uk/dp/B07FFNN41F/ref=pe_3187911_189395841_TE_dp_1))